# Regex Match a character which is not followed by another specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a CodeMirror extension for Brackets. To defineSimpleCodeMode I need to do some pattern matching and I'm trying to figure out how to achieve $subject.

e.g.

Match `<` of all the html tags

```
<body>
```

And ignore html tags which are followed by `<%`

```
<% if %>
```

**Note: I only want to get the starting `<` of it**

If some can help me out it would be a great help. Please do let me know if you need anymore details.

Thanks!

Comment: using a regex to parse a template string, can be a very bad idea

Comment: Hi @DanielA.White this is to write an CodeMode extension.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While this seems to be a bad idea, I can see two ways of doing it :

## 1. Searching for `<` followed by anything but the `%` character, then ignoring it

`(<)(?:[^%])`

The `[^]` sequence allows you to search for anything but the following character.

The `(?:)` sequence is for non capturing groups.

## 2. (Better, if supported) Searching for input not followed by % with a negative lookahead

`<(?!%)`

The `(?!)` sequence succeeds if it doesn't match the following character, but is not captured.

## If you also want to do it for `%>`, you can just "reverse" the first option :

`(?:[^%])(>)`

## Or you  need a negative lookbehind :

(careful here, the lookahead won't work as you need to go backwards)

`(?<!%)>`

Comment: Hi @Baptiste, Thanks for the answer. It almost do what I wanted.How is it possible to ignore the second charater which is after `<` ?

Comment: I don't know what tool you are working with, but you could just replace what you get with  the `$1` variable with most of them.

Comment: @JeradRutnam what you you mean the second character? It's already ignoring the second `%`

Comment: Can we add `$1` along with the match `(<)[^%]` somehow?

Comment: yes, It ignores `<%` but selects `<b` for an example. but I want to get the match substring after. e.g. only `<`

Comment: This is just did the trick. Thanks a lot @Baptiste, for your great time.

Comment: @Baptiste, one more question does this (`(?<!%)>`) remove everything behind `>` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking there exactly. It only captures `>`, when it is not directly preceded by %.

Comment: Oh ok. Cool. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Comment: I am using a custom Html tag '<ignore>' will this code work properly? or do I need to specify a muti-character string differently. I am having a problem where it is not working at the very beginning of the string...
       (?:[^<ignore>])(\()